# TypeError: encoding without a string argument on twitter account activity api

Tags: python, flask

I am setting up a flask server that will act as a webhook to the twitter account activity api. However I came up with this issue that I have no idea how to solve, I'm fairly new to programming so please bear with me. I just used this repository https://github.com/RickRedSix/twitter-webhook-boilerplate-python/blob/master/Main.py

This is the error:

```
line 28, in twitterCrcValidation
    key=bytes(CONSUMER_SECRET, encoding ='utf-8'),
TypeError: encoding without a string argument
```

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask, request, send_from_directory, make_response
from http import HTTPStatus

import Twitter, hashlib, hmac, base64, os, logging, json
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('.env')

CONSUMER_SECRET = os.getenv('CONSUMER_SECRET')
CURRENT_USER_ID = os.getenv('CURRENT_USER_ID')

app = Flask(__name__)

#generic index route
@app.route('/')
def default_route():
    return send_from_directory('www', 'index.html')

#The GET method for webhook should be used for the CRC check
#TODO: add header validation (compare_digest https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/hmac.html)
@app.route("/webhook", methods=["GET"])
def twitterCrcValidation():

    crc = request.args['crc_token']

    validation = hmac.new(
        key=bytes(CONSUMER_SECRET, encoding ='utf-8'),
        msg=bytes(crc, encoding = 'utf-8'),
        digestmod = hashlib.sha256
    )
    digested = base64.b64encode(validation.digest())
    response = {
        'response_token': 'sha256=' + format(str(digested)[2:-1])
    }
    print('responding to CRC call')

    return json.dumps(response)

#The POST method for webhook should be used for all other API events
#TODO: add event-specific behaviours beyond Direct Message and Like
@app.route("/webhook", methods=["POST"])
def twitterEventReceived():

    requestJson = request.get_json()

    #dump to console for debugging purposes
    print(json.dumps(requestJson, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

    if 'favorite_events' in requestJson.keys():
        #Tweet Favourite Event, process that
        likeObject = requestJson['favorite_events'][0]
        userId = likeObject.get('user', {}).get('id')

        #event is from myself so ignore (Favourite event fires when you send a DM too)
        if userId == CURRENT_USER_ID:
            return ('', HTTPStatus.OK)

        Twitter.processLikeEvent(likeObject)

    elif 'direct_message_events' in requestJson.keys():
        #DM recieved, process that
        eventType = requestJson['direct_message_events'][0].get("type")
        messageObject = requestJson['direct_message_events'][0].get('message_create', {})
        messageSenderId = messageObject.get('sender_id')

        #event type isnt new message so ignore
        if eventType != 'message_create':
            return ('', HTTPStatus.OK)

        #message is from myself so ignore (Message create fires when you send a DM too)
        if messageSenderId == CURRENT_USER_ID:
            return ('', HTTPStatus.OK)

        Twitter.processDirectMessageEvent(messageObject)

    else:
        #Event type not supported
        return ('', HTTPStatus.OK)

    return ('', HTTPStatus.OK)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 65010.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 65010))
    gunicorn_logger = logging.getLogger('gunicorn.error')
    app.logger.handlers = gunicorn_logger.handlers
    app.logger.setLevel(gunicorn_logger.level)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

Comment: Seems like your `CONSUMER_SECRET` environment variable is not set. Try setting the variable before running your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to verify input to your program and environment variables are no exception. As a minumum, check that these variables actually exist. `os.getenv` returns `None` if the environment variable doesn't exist. `None` is not a string and thus your error. You could do this with a slightly different `os` call.

```
CONSUMER_SECRET = os.environ['CONSUMER_SECRET']
CURRENT_USER_ID = os.environ['CURRENT_USER_ID']
```

Now an exception is raised on failure. This could be wrapped in an exception handler if you want different error reporting than the standard traceback.